# Passing array of React components to useState returns empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Very simple code here. I'm wondering if this is the expected outcome. I'm upgrading an `npm` module and it requires I pass these items to `useState` which was not previously necessary. Unfortunately, I guess this can't be done with `useState`? Am I right? I'd love to be wrong.

---

Where `props.items` contains an array of class-based React components, `useState` returns an empty array:

```js
const [items, set] = useState(props.items);
```

## Input:

[image]

## Output:

[image]

*Note, images use prop spreading inside of array because I'm out of ideas besides, rework all the things.

Answer (score 12):

This is not really recommanded you better do it in the `useEffect` because `Props` in Initial State is an [anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e).

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
    setItems(props.items);
  },[props.items]);
```

Comment: this will do set the state only once on mount though. whenever `props.items` changes in parent it will not be reflected unless `props.items` is present in dependency array of `useEffect`

Comment: I'm aware, but struggling with very ehhhh pre-release documentation. Let's ignore the fact that it should not be done, can anyone tell me *WHY* the result is an empty array? That's all I really care about here, although your answer is noted and is important for anyone who happens upon this via Google.

Comment: yup of course could you add an example in codesandbox or codepen so we can help

Comment: If I could reproduce it in CodeSandbox, I'd certainly have included it. Unfortunately, limited examples I've created in CodeSandbox work as you'd expect, not returning an empty array. Transpilation is fun, I guess. ---

`set` is indeed a reserved word, but I'm not really using the hook as intended at all, in fact, I'm not even using this code anymore. I'm only interested in why the returned array is empty, and that's the case whether I call it `set` or `setItems` or anything else.

Comment: `set` is not a reserved word :) @Taki

Answer (score 2):

You should have no issues with using react element array as the input to useState. But, whenever you initialize your state with props coming from parent, you also need to re-update your state once the prop from parent changes. Otherwise it will point to the old state passed down from parent in the first pass. And the way to do that is to do a setItems with useEffect hook

```
useEffect(() => {
   setItems(props.items)
}, [props.items])
```

btw this will only check for the reference equality between the old and the new array, if you want to do deep comparison, you should probably be using something like [use-deep-compare-effect](https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect)

Comment: this is a hard anti-pattern. Why copy props to state instead of just using props? There can't possibly be a single reason to do so

Comment: There is one good reason to do it. Trying to follow poor, pre-release documentation, and trying to adhere to it to get a working minimum viable implementation. Once you understand, then you can rip out the anti-pattern.

Otherwise, yes; there are really no valid reasons I can think of.

Comment: @Max *"There can't possibly be a single reason to do so"* Not even for setting some initial values to be modified in state later? Its an anti-pattern if you're just duplicating props into state. But I think there are legitimate use cases for setting them like this (even if this is not one of them). Like an edit form - you may receive initial values from an API, you pass them to your form as props, set the form values in state from the props, and then allow changes to them in state.

Comment: exactly, initial values, and only once in `useState`. not in `useEffect` with dependencies like in this example @BrianThompson

Comment: It still applies. Putting it in a `useEffect` with that dependency only means it will update when the prop changes. Maybe the initial values change based on the URL, but the component never remounts. Maybe the initial values are not immediately available while they are being fetched from a server. Bottom line - Setting state from props is not inherently an anti-pattern. Only when the state does not need to change over time.

Comment: @Max I don't know what the author is doing later with the state initialized from the props. I'm merely pointing out what to do to properly re-initialize the value if needed.  There are legitimate use cases where you have a component that initialized its state  as pointed out by Brian Thompson. And if you don't re-initialize it through useEffect, you won't receive the values if they are changed in parent. Again, depending on the use case, you might not care about later values passed down from parent component. So, all the possibilities are valid based on what your use case is :)

Comment: when value doesn't change over time, you use `props`, not state copied from props. The only reason to put data in state is if you want to change it over time. In that case, copying props in useEffect will effectively erase your changes every time prop changes @BrianThompson

Comment: @max exactly. And depending on your use-case you might want that to happen sometimes (I don't know if thats what author intended though :shrug:)